# ¿Cuales son las desventajas de usar un campo varchar(max) MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente, trabajo en el soporte de una aplicación web donde los usuarios hacen pedidos, el sistema funciona de maravilla, pero hay un apartado en el hemos tenido dificultades, la bitácora, cuando un usuario registra un pedido se utiliza `var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); jsonSerialiser.Serialize(infoPedido);` para convertir toda la información del pedido en una cadena de caracteres y poder guardarla en la tabla bitácora, la razón de que esté  diseñado así es porque la bitácora se usa en todos los módulos de productos, producción, entrega, por lo que no tenemos un esquema especifico de que campos guardar por lo que se guarda así en un campo string, en un campo que se define como `varchar(600)`, el sistema tiene cerca de 6 meses operando y al parecer cubría nuestras necesidades, pero ha ocurrido un par de ocasiones que los pedidos no se guardan porque truena al hacer insert en la bitácora, esto es porque en promedio los usuarios suben un máximo de 3 productos por pedido por lo que la cantidad de caracteres promedia los 600, pero ha ocurrido que un usuario ya registró 6 productos entonces subimos la cantidad de caracteres a 1000 y el día de hoy un usuario registró 17, la cantidad de caracteres se disparó súbitamente, llegados a este punto está claro que la información que registran los usuarios ya no es algo que podamos tener controlado por lo que consideramos utilizar el `varchar(max)`. La mayoría de los artículos que he leído los usuarios saben mas o menos que cantidad de caracteres es lo que necesitan cubrir, en mi caso es demasiado variable (aunque no sea tan común) también he leído que al poner el varchar en máximo permitiría guardar hasta un máximo de 2gb en caracteres, es obvio que está sobradísimo, pero ¿qué alternativas tengo?, si aplico esto ¿afectaré al rendimiento de los inserts?

Mencionar también que esta tabla no se consulta nunca, a menos que halla algún problema con un cliente o sospechen que alguien viola los códigos de conducta de la empresa.

Espero alguien pueda solventar mi duda, saludos y gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. `[modo="broma"]` `Una desventaja es que podrías guardar largos párrafos` **`sin usar punto y aparte`** 
 `[/modo="broma"]`. Ya en serio, por favor mejora tu pregunta, usa el punto y aparte. Ver una pregunta planteada de esa manera desanima al más altruista. [Pulsa aquí para editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/206151/edit). Gracias.

Comment: Siento decirte, que guardar la tabla asi fue una mala idea. Una tabla canonica (mas si no se usa nunca, solo para auditoria) hubiera sido mucho mejor. Y si como vos decis el sistema es bastante nuevo, seria algo para pensar..

Comment: @A.Cedano [bromamode=on] ya te agrego un punto. feliz? [bromamode=off]. No no.. trata de explicar un poco mejor lo que tenes, ejemplos. Ojo porque tu pregunta se acerca demasiado peligrosamente a ser basada en opiniones, no se si existe una respuesta "correcta" a lo que estas preguntando, si no, opiniones sobre que deberias hacer

Comment: Tal vez te interese esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server.

Y 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type

Comment: Puedes consultar el articulo titulado [*Performance comparison of varchar(max) vs. varchar(N)*](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/) de [@RemusRusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) y también [este otro](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/) donde se aborda la cuestión de los índices.

Comment: A.Cedano tomo nota para mis futuras preguntas, gracias. gbianchi se que es una mala idea, pero esto ya está en producción y solo me tocó dar soporte. ¿porqué esto se presta para ser pregunta basada en  opiniones?, presenté mi caso específico, debe existir algo específico que utilizar (aunque comprendo que quizá existan mas detalles a evaluar para tomar una decisión).
Francis Yourem  y A. Cedano gracias por los enlaces, ahora tengo una idea mas clara, en cuanto haga pruebas publicaré mi solución.

Comment: Mas allá del deseo que la pregunta este mejor redactada, si como parece ser, la bitacora la usas para registro de transacciones, no tendrias grandes diferencias de performance entre uno u otro caso. Sivien es mucho mas performante un varchar(7000) que un varchar(max), a nivel de 1 asignacion que es lo que el sistema hace, puedes hablar de diferencias del orden de 2 o 3 ms. Nadie notaria la diferencia.
Sobre las consultas a la bitacora serán mas lentas, como tu dices, la tabla se consulta en raras ocasiones, que tu SELECT demore 50s o 55s en algo que haces una vez al mes no afectará al sistema